# How to display values from table, modify them , save them again

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display values from table and want to modify the values on form submit.

> here is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME");

//Get and store values into new variable

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name[]   = $row['name'];
    $status[] = $row['status'];

}
```

//run for loop to identify values

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
        echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td>" . $name[$i] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input  name='offer_new_name' size='5' type='text' value='$status[$i]' /></td>";

}
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Save New Values" name="save_new">';
echo "</form>";

if (isset($_REQUEST['save_new'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
        echo "name:$name[$i]<br>";
        echo "status:$status[$i]";
    }
}
```

When I click Save New Values , it displays the old values ,, taken from db.
Please guide me how to save

```
echo "<td><input  name='new_status' size='5' type='text' value='$status[$i]' /></td>";
```

into new variable for each name and save them into the same table again.

Please guide me if my approach is wrong towards this requirement.

> Update1:

table structure:

```
id       name:               status:
auto     name1                  0
auto     name2                  1
auto     name3                  0
```

Where this runs,

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $name[]   = $row['name'];
        $status[] = $row['status'];

    }
```

values are stored like this

```
 $name[0]  
  $status[0] 
  $name[1]  
  $status[1]
  $name[2]  
  $status[2]
```

I can run update query like this

```
UPDATE TABLE set status=$status[0] where name= $name[0]
```

Comment: where is your `update` query ?

Comment: i will handle update query ,, first i want to echo , values,, once new values are taken update can be run

Comment: you want to view the new `submitted` result ? not the db updated results, right ?

Comment: firstly , i want to view the results from db,, then once modified ,, i want to view the modified results

Comment: then you have to provide your update query example !

Comment: format will be like this : --------
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE TABLENAME set  status=$status[$i]  WHERE name=$name[$i]  ");

Comment: @sadiarehman look at my answer, I think this will help you

Comment: @LucaJung , replied to your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the following line should be in the `<form></form>`

```
echo "<td><input  name='new_status' size='5' type='text' value='$status[$i]' /></td>";
```

Second, this code block should be on top of your script:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['save_new'])){
  //Your update query
}
```

In this code block you need an update query, which updates your database e.g

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET a = new_value WHERE b = c;
```

This is the variable you can access the entered value;

```
$_POST['new_status'];
```

Lastly I can strongly recommend to use prepared statements. Otherwise your code will be open for SQL-Injections.

Pseudo code:

```
<?php
//if the submit button is pressed, update the Database
if (isset($_REQUEST['save_new'])) {
    //Update your Database
}

//get the new values from Database
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME");

//store values into new variable
$name = array();
$status = array();
$id = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name[]   = $row['name'];
    $status[] = $row['status'];
    $id[] = $row['id'];
}

//create HTML-From
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    echo "<tr> ";
    echo "<td>" . $name[$i] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input  name='new_status' size='5' type='text' value='$status[$i]' /></td>";
}
echo '<input type="submit" value="Save New Values" name="save_new">';
echo "</form>";
?>
```

This 'new id' can be saved as a hidden input in your script:

```
$indecipherable_id = (int)$id * 7258289382234; //Only a example --> use a more complex algorithm!
```

Before your update query you can decrypt the `id` and select the row.

Comment: What do you mean with new values? The value you entered in the form?

Comment: once i get the values from db ,, i will modify them , how to get modified (inputted ) values ??

Comment: Ok the values, you get from db are stored in $name and $status

Comment: if i update multiple values , how does the query will know about this ..
 $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE TABLENAME set status=$status WHERE name=$name");

Comment: No, the new value from input is $_POST['offer_new_name']. If you want to update your db then you have to use this variable. and form multiple values you can use set a=b, c=d, e=f WHERE ...

Comment: But in order to update it you have to keep the old value. This can be down e.g by a session value.

Comment: not yet .. could not find a way  oon how to write update query. as i am not sure where the values are being stored and how to match status with name
. $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE TABLENAME set status=$status WHERE name=$name");

Comment: @sadiarehman Where the value is stored in your db or in the php script? Can you give some more informations, then I may help you

Comment: this is where i get the values 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name[]   = $row['name'];
    $status[] = $row['status'];

}
$name[0] and $status[0] . like that..

Comment: Ok and which value would you change in database? And in which way do you identify the row to update?

Comment: @sadiarehman Ok you would only change the status, not the name?

Comment: yes, name will not be changed i need only status to be changed w.r.t name

Comment: @sadiarehman Then you need to save the name somewhere. It is very unsafe to save it as a hidden input. You need a algorithm that makes it indecipherable. e.g you fetch the ID of them and multiply it with several numbers. look my example

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that gives you food for thought. It's not a final solution, you have to adjust it.